# how to find my postgresDb is enterprice or community edition?

Tags: postgresql

How to check my running postgresDb is enterprice edition or Community edition? Is there any option to migrate from Community edition to Enterprice edition?

Comment: There's no such thing as "PostgresDb Enterprise Edition" - where are you getting your information from?

Comment: @Dai, yes there is [EDB](https://www.enterprisedb.com/). If you downloaded from here [Windows download](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/) you got the community edition via an installer created by EDB. If you had the EDB Advanced Server(enterprise) version you would have/are getting a bill.